# Android sort Listview, according to user id

Tags: android, sorting, listview

I have a listview which contain 3 different values.

The values:
**Top problem** (getField_top_problem), 
**user id** (getUid) 
 **difficulty**(getField_difficulty)

I would like to sort the list like this.
First part:
Check which user is logged in. Get all the Top problems for that user.
The Top problems from the logged in user, needs to be sorted according to most difficult first.

Second part / Rest of list.
Need to be sorted according to the most difficult first. Does not matter if there is a Top problem from another user, which is not logged in. (If not sure, check image - red box)

If its still unclear, i have added an image. It should look like this.
[image]

My progress so far.
I was able to sort it, Top problem first for all users, not just the logged in user. Need to sort it, according to logged in user's Top problem. The id for logged in user is saved as a string.

```
//Example logged in user id (uid)
String uid = "2";
```

Any help would be appreciated.

```
 protected void onPostExecute(final List<OcdModel> result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        dialog.dismiss();

        //uid - user id that is logged in.
        //Sort - Top problem of user logged in first.
        //sort the rest according to difficulty

        //check which user is logged in.
        //Boolean user1 = a1.getUid().equals(uid);

        Collections.sort(result, new Comparator<OcdModel>() {
            @Override
            public int compare(OcdModel a1, OcdModel a2) {

                //Top problem first. Arrange row with most difficult first in top problems list.
                Integer tp1 = Integer.parseInt(a1.getField_top_problem().toString());
                Integer tp2 = Integer.parseInt(a2.getField_top_problem().toString());
                int tpComp = tp1.compareTo(tp2);
                //return b1.compareTo(b2);
                if (tpComp != 0) {
                    return tpComp;
                } else {
                    int b1 = Integer.parseInt(a1.getField_difficulty().toString());
                    int b2 = Integer.parseInt(a2.getField_difficulty().toString());
                    return (int) (b1-b2);
                }
            }
        });
        Collections.reverse(result);
        //TODO Need to set data
        OcdListAdapter adapter = new OcdListAdapter(getApplicationContext(), R.layout.row_ocd_list, result);
        lvToolbox.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: You have to get help from api developers. You need to pass different params key and values for each request like sort : (first-part some value identifier) , sort : (second-part some value identifier) etc

Answer (score 1):

> You need to create multiple camparator like this

```
public class ModelChainedComparator implements Comparator<OcdModel> {
    private List<Comparator<OcdModel>> listComparators;
    @SafeVarargs
    public ModelChainedComparator(Comparator<OcdModel>... comparators) {
        this.listComparators = Arrays.asList(comparators);
    }
    @Override
    public int compare(OcdModel a1, OcdModel a2) {
        for (Comparator<OcdModel> comparator : listComparators) {
            int result = comparator.compare(a1, a2);
            if (result != 0) {
                return result;
            }
        }
        return 0;
    }
}

public class ModelUserLoginComparator implements Comparator<OcdModel> {
    @Override
    public int compare(OcdModel a1, OcdModel a2) {
        return Boolean.valueOf(a2.isUserLogedIn).compareTo(Boolean.valueOf(a1.isUserLogedIn));
    }
}

public class ModelDeficultyComparator implements Comparator<OcdModel> {
    @Override
    public int compare(OcdModel a1, OcdModel a2) {
        int firstObject = Integer.parseInt(a1.getField_difficulty().toString());
        int secondObject = Integer.parseInt(a2.getField_difficulty().toString());
        return firstObject < secondObject ? 1 : (firstObject == secondObject ? 0 : -1);
    }
}
```

Than you have to use this like

```
    ArrayList<OcdModel> list = getList();
    Collections.sort(list, new ModelChainedComparator(
                    new ModelUserLoginComparator(),
                    new ModelDeficultyComparator())
            );
```

Let me know if not work

Comment: Just a quick question. In your example, where do you check that it is the logged in user? And not just comparing user ids? Sorry, I am still new to programming.

Comment: "where do you check that it is the logged in user"  I have not check that in my code but if you want to check than you have to add one field in your OcdModel

Comment: like boolean isUserLogin      than check if isUserLogin is true than put it in ArrayList than sort just give me some time all give you code of this